# How to avoid nested AggregateException when using Task.ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have an async method in a .NET 4.5 C# component:

```
public async Task<T> GetResultAsync()
{
    return PerformOperationAsync();
}
```

If PerformOperationAsync throws an exception, then I can catch an AggregateException on a client side, unwrap it and get the original exception thrown.

However, if I have slightly more complicated code:

```
public async Task<T> GetResultAsync()
{
    return PerformOperationAsync().ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        var result = x.Result;
        return DoSomethingWithResult(result);
    }, cancellationToken);
}
```

... then in case an exception occurs, the client catches a nested AggregateException, so it has to flatten it prior getting the original one.

Should this behavior be avoided or does client have to expect possibly nested AggregateException and call Flatten to unwrap all its levels? And if this behavior should be avoided by the component developer, then what's the right way to deal with it in ContinueWith scenario? I have plenty of similar situations, so I am trying to find the most lightweight method of handling them.

Comment: Do you really want to deal with manual continuations? They are a huge pain (although still awesome compared to callbacks etc.). Even if you're on .NET 4.0, you can use the async targeting pack to use `await` instead.

Comment: Of course I don't want to deal with manual continuations unless absolutely necessary. But there are cases I have to and I wonder how to properly handle AggregateException in such case.

Comment: Well, in general, you can just follow the usual rules for handling and throwing exceptions. Should the topmost caller be even aware of what's going two layers of indirection away? Should it expect e.g. an `IOException`, or some `MySpecificException`? For example, Microsoft Orleans considers each indirection a separate scope for aggregate exception, so each asynchronous call is a new layer in the resulting aggregate exception. Does that make *sense* for your case? It really is just basic system / API architecture, it's not specific to tasks or aggregate exceptions :)

Comment: Thanks @Luaan, this makes sense. And it in fact took just a short time to revise my code to stop using continuation and just use await/async. Works much smoother now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C#5 async/await will help you deal with continuations and proper exception handling while simplifying the code.

```
public async Task<T> GetResultAsync()
{
    var result = await PerformOperationAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return DoSomethingWithResult(result);
}
```

Your method is already marked as async, is it intended ?

---

To keep the continuation you can provide a `TaskContinuationOptions` with `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` value :

```
PerformOperationAsync().ContinueWith(x =>
{
    var result = x.Result;
    return DoSomethingWithResult(result);
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

or use the awaiter to raise the original exception

```
PerformOperationAsync().ContinueWith(x =>
{
    var result = x.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return DoSomethingWithResult(result);
}, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: I thinks I have oversimplified this example. In fact there is more logic involved in continuation labmda, so I can't just get rid of ContinueWith clause.

Comment: Thanks. But actually your first suggestion made me revise my code and you were right: I was able to rewrite it just to use await, get rid of continuations and nested exceptions.

Comment: `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` will actually make the problem worse: If `PerformOperationAsync` throws an exception, it will swallowed, and instead a `TaskCanceledException` will be thrown.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to [Guillaume's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143503/guillaume) answer, I am using a little extension method

```
public static class Ext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Wait for task synchronously, then return result. Avoid AggregateExceptions 
    /// as it would be generated by asyncTask.Result.
    /// </summary>
    public static T SyncResult<T>(this Task<T> asyncTask) 
                                    => asyncTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Instead of `var result = x.Result;`, use it like this:

```
var result = x.SyncResult();
```

It does the same as [Guillaume](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143503/guillaume) explained, but is shorter to use and easier to memorize.

Comment: Upvoted. I have created an identically implemented method for my own use, and I have named it `Wait2`. I don't like this name, but IMHO the `SyncResult` is not much better either. The native `Task.Result` is not less synchronous than this method!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes, both are synchronous, but  as I understood from the comments and from Guillaume's answer is that `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` handles exceptions better than `.Result` does - and I bet you have seen those AggregateExceptions which you want to avoid: It is difficult to find out the root cause with those. If one finds a better method name than `SyncResult`, please let me know ;-)